# Help identify 80's kids/youth novel about an archeologist who finds a skull with a symbiont in it

Tags: story-identification, alien-invasion

In the start/mid 80's I read a novel in the school library about an archeologist who finds a buried skull with one wide front tooth instead of the usual two. He takes it to his lab where a "symbiont" organism crawls out and takes over his brain.

I read it in Danish, and I *assume* it was translated from English. I don't remember the name of the author.

The book had some very fancy neon 80's artwork on the cover, and it was one in a series of two or three. Its title was "Invasion fra rummet" in Danish, which means "Invasion from space", which of course yields no useful results on google.

I can add probably useless bonus info that the book's first chapter was filmatized for a youth book review tv program on Danish national tv in 1985-86 with Henning Moritzen as the archeologist.

Comment: The "useless" information about the dramatization featuring Henning Moritzen would not be useless.  Except that neither the IMDB or Wikipedia seem to list that episode.  https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0605786/?ref_=nv_sr_srsg_0    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henning_Moritzen  I suggest that you try to remember the title of that youth book review program from 1985-86 and try looking up the specific episodes.